# Making a mouth in sculpt

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I've been making a dragon head in sculpt and the head has no hole where the mouth cavity is. I already made a mouth cavity inside the head. is there a way to join them together so the exterior of the mouth connects to the mouth cavity? Sorry if this is a dumb question I'm new to blender

Comment: did you try the boolean modifier tool?

Comment: I tried using boolean modifier it joined the mouth cavity to the external part of the mouth but didn't make an opening where the mouth opens.

Comment: So you want to remove some faces to "open" the hole to show the cavity?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or blend file?

Comment: after deleting the connecting faces the mouth works perfectly now, thank you so much for the help!